# Type error when when trying to override a generic function in a concrete implementation of an abstract class

Tags: scala, generics, abstract

The error can be reproduced in the console with the following code.

```
case class SomeClass(name: String)

abstract class Factory() {
  protected def create[U](name: String) : U
}

class SomeFactory extends Factory() {
  override def create[SomeClass](name: String) = SomeClass(name)
}
```

> <console>:11: error: type mismatch;
>     found   : SomeClass(in object $iw)
>     required: SomeClass(in method create)
>          override def create[SomeClass](name: String) = SomeClass(name)

Comment: It looks like you need the generic parameter to go on the `Factory` class? At the moment `create` needs to support any type specified by the client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
case class SomeClass(name: String)

abstract class Factory[U]() {
  protected def create(name: String) : U
}

class SomeFactory extends Factory[SomeClass] {
  def create(name: String) = SomeClass(name)
}
```

(I'm assuming you meant for `SomeFactory` to extend `Factory`)